# Is it possible for a Microsoft Teams bot to download a meeting transcript?

Tags: microsoft-graph-teams

I'm trying to figure out whether it's possible for a bot to download a Teams meeting transcript.  If I start recording/transcription for a call/meeting, the transcript appears interspersed with the meeting chat after the call is complete (along with the recording link).  If I use the new recording storage options (to store to OneDrive), then I can retrieve the a/v recording from the OneDrive storage, but I'm not sure how I can get at the transcript.  If I look at the meeting chat in Teams, the transcript and recording are listed there, but they're not actually chat messages.  If you call something like this:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me/chats/19%3Ameeting_ZDdlMjA3OGYtNmFlOC00OTIxLTlhODYtNDRlMmNjNjQ4ZWQ1%40thread.v2/messages
```

You'll get the chat messages in the meeting thread, which does not include the anchor for the recording/transcript download.  Looking closer, it appears that this is listed as an "event" in the conversation, similar to a participant add/remove, but I haven't been able to find a graph API call that will let you audit those types of events.  Is there a currently a way to retrieve a call transcript using a graph API call?